# Как в CheckBox в android делать так, чтобы при отмене галочки отменялось и действие чекбокса?

Tags: java, android, checkbox

Есть программа для заказа кофе, если пользователь ставит галочку на пункте *"с шоколадом"*, цена увеличивается на 3 доллара, я делал это с помощью команды `android:onClick="имя метода"` в элементе `CheckBox`, но проблема в том, что при снятии галочки, цена не только не уменьшается обратно, но даже увеличивается, я знаю, что это происходит из-за того использую не ту команду, но что мне использовать в данном случае не знаю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне использовать вместо `onClick`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо использовать примерно такую конструкцию (использование `onClick()` - здесь не поможет)

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

       @Override
       public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
           if(isChecked)
               // увеличиваем цену кофе
           else
               //уменьшаем цену кофе
       }
   }
);
```

P.S. Использование `android:onClick` является антипаттерном - не советую

Comment: Благодарствую!)